# Converting character string to integer

Tags: fortran, string-conversion

This is a follow up to my [get_command_argument() question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873497/fortran-2003-passing-arguments-to-executable-from-command-line/19877327?noredirect=1#comment29568890_19877327).

I'm reading a command line argument (`arg`) into a Fortran program. Then I want to store the value of `arg` as an integer. `ichar()` doesn't do the job.

This seems kind of basic, so clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any hints?

```
program test_get_command_argument
   integer :: i,j
   character(len=32) :: arg

   i = 0
   do
       call get_command_argument(i,arg)
       if (LEN_TRIM(arg) == 0) EXIT

       write (*,*) trim(arg)
       i = i + 1
   end do

   j = ichar(arg)


end program
```

Comment: got it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ICHAR.html), gee, Fortran is a lot different from C ;-)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark doesn't `command_argument_count()` just return the number of arguments (I read that [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COMMAND_005fARGUMENT_005fCOUNT.html)), but I'd still like to work with the actual values of the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the "internal files" capability.
You should have a statement like `read(arg,*) j`.
This will read the character variable `arg` as if it were a file
and store the result into `j`.

Comment: I just tried that. I put **read(arg,'(I32)') j** in the line after the call get_command_argument(), but at runtime I get the error: **Bad integer for item 1 in list input**

Comment: got it, I am so used to argc and argv in C, that I totally missed the point that the **first argument** in *get_command_argument()* is actually the calling of the executable, duh. :-)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by first argument...fortran is generally 1-based, not 0-based as C is. `get_command_argument` is the only exception I've seen, where `0` means the name of the program and `1` means the first argument sent to the program.

Comment: yup, it's the only exception I've seen so far (in my very short fortran career) as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but an extended comment:

That's a bizarre way to loop over the command line arguments. What's wrong with the straightforward and obvious

```
do i = 1, command_argument_count()
   call get_command_argument(i,arg)
   ! do funky stuff    
end do
```

Comment: I agree. In found this example on the [gcc.gnu.org website](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html).