# Shell parameter as an arguments for Fortran

Tags: function, shell, fortran, arguments, executable

I would like to compute easily the square of a number with the following shell line

./exe parameter

Here is the fortran code

```
PROGRAM

    REAL*8 :: x,fx

    fx=x**2

    print*,'The square of ',x,' is ',fx

END PROGRAM
```

I want to x to be parameter, which line can i use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arguments to executable from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873497/passing-arguments-to-executable-from-command-line)

Comment: Seems good ! Thank you